# Should I change my attitude or way of talking based on the group conversation I have?

Tags: conversations, apologies, social-media, chatting

**Background and Briefs:**

I have been told multiple times that I don't make good jokes and usually "bore" them with poor comments and also I am the most frequent user of English words in the group which was reduced much as due to opposition  of many people.

Now, in a recent incident one of my friend asked us all to notify him weather anyone has problem attending to farewell(of end of our school{finally!} )  or not I felt a bit bad as nobody in the class really bothers about my words (Except 2-3 friends who still thinks I have poor jokes but still don't bother about it) so I wrote

> ME:I know nobody cares but still thought to mention 
>   Not coming to farewell

and the reply was

> Don't annoy us just tell Yes or no

Okay maybe I should have only said yes or no but maybe  I wanted to say that as trying to make them feel bad at least a bit.

Then I just sent a screenshot of Translation of "Not Coming" to our common language in which we use to talk.

Then another one said

> > annoyed again

After that a series of comments when I was offline that how annoying I am and should be removed out of the group.

Another one said

> Guy1:We will remove him on his next 
> Guy2: Delete comments about him else he would read and annoy again

I left the group Stating :

> > Let it be , You guys don't Deserve my Company

Also there are only few of the people on the group who say these which are actually active participants in our WhatsApp Group.

**Main Question:**

Should I change the way I talk as It has made me think about my social skills or become silent in b/w the conversations{so far not working} or any other suggestion to get through these chats and without getting annoyed just get the information I need about in the activities in the classroom in future?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear: You need to be part of the chat to get information about school events? The chat also contains personal conversations? People in the chat want to exclude you, claiming your attitude is the problem? What exactly is your question: Do you want to know if you are at fault? Do you want to know how to not seem "boring/annoying"? Do you want to still get Information in a environment where you feel bullied?

Comment: Also, be aware we don't make decisions for you... You might do better to answer the questions above and rephrase the post to ask how to handle the situation...

Comment: How old are you, where are you from? Do I understand correctly that you thought people should care about you more but they don't because you are not that funny and as a result you got angry about it in some class what's app group? Sorry, it's a bit confusing. How about not writing angry/passive aggressive comments in the future?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your problem you're often trying to communicate in a way that bores people around you.

- You've been told that countless times it seems.
- You kept doing something that you've been told was ennoying them.
- When the finally lost their last bit of patience towards it you left stating you were better than them :

  > Let it be , You guys don't Deserve my Company

Something strikes me there even though I wasn't there so I can't judge how annoying it may have (or have not) been for them, when they expressed (even if it was rude from them) their want to exclude you from the chat group you answered with an arrogant and immature statement.
I'm telling you this to help you, let me explain :

Even if they weren't realy annoyed by your previous behaviour and did this because they choose to sort of bully you (it may happen), by keeping to behave the same way you just gave them the way (and reasons) to keep doing it.

What you could have done to prevent it :

1. The first time you were told it was annoying ask why, and focus on not doing it again.
2. If it happened again even though you thought what you said was realy fun, note that it's not their case and prevent from doing it again.
3. If participating to the conversations, and making jokes feels important to you try to listen how they joke with each other, and adapt yourself to them (even if I don't recommend that)
4. If you can't or don't want to adapt yourself, just leave it be, ignore them and do things your way. It's school, life goes on after it, don't feel too tied to them. (highly recommend this one)

To give you a clear answer to your question :

> Should I change the way I talk as It has made me think about my social skills or become silent

**It's up to you, take time to think about what you want.**
I'm sorry I can't give you a better answer because it's realy how it is.
If you realy want to try to fit in the group then give it a try, stay silent for a time, learn the codes, and try. But chances are that you wo't success.

If not then feel free and relieved to go your way, focus on what you love and you'll find people who will love the same things and with whom you'll be at your ease.

Comment: imho due to his descriptions it seems as if he is more something we in austria often call "klassenopfer". Someone that is blamed for eveyrhing, made jokes upon and so forth. I think this might have more to do with how he presents himself because they dont seem to be real "friends". It might be that the way he writes is less the problem but the whole package that might not fit with theese people.

Comment: @MansNotHot That's why I spoke about them "sort of bullying" him/her and gave advices about how to go on his/her way (alone), it's a case I know pretty well and which happens regardless the country you live in I believe

Comment: Yeah i know :) And it was not meant as critique to your answer :)